# How to move text field up when keyboard pops up

Tags: ios, swift

I am moving in from objective c to swift. Can anyone specify how to stop the keyboard from hiding the textfield. The problem is; I have some text field in my view controller, when the user clicks on the last text field near to bottom of the screen, the keyboard appears and hide the textfield. Is there any easy way to solve this or should i have to use scroll view ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. What would you do in objective-C? Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this library called IQKeyboardManager:
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

> Install pod file pod 'IQKeyboardManager’ . And in your app delegate

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText = "Done”
        return true
    }
}
```

You can change the following properties of `IQKeyboardManager` as well

```swift
IQKeyboardManager.shared.overrideKeyboardAppearance = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardAppearance = .dark
IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarBarTintColor = UIColor.cyan
IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarDoneBarButtonItemImage = UIImage(named: "<#T##String#>")

IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
IQKeyboardManager.shared.placeholderFont = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 20.0)
IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldPlayInputClicks = true //default
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add your textfield delegate here
    textField.delegate = self

    // Add observer for keyboard events
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Get keyboard height
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
          let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else {
        return
    }
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height

    // Update bottom constraint of text field
    bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight

    // Animate the view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Reset bottom constraint of text field
    bottomConstraint.constant = 0

    // Animate the view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Dismiss the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Makesure to change your code according to your iboutlets names and your logic.